# Grouping string using Regular Expression

Tags: c#, .net, regex, dotliquid

I have the below string

```
validates="required positiveInteger" label="Enter the Total Value." name="totalvalue" visibleif="hasvalue:Yes"
```

So the string has 4 attributes `validates`,`label`,`name` and `visibleif` with respective value

I am using [dotliquid's regular expression utility class](https://github.com/dotliquid/dotliquid/blob/master/src/DotLiquid/Util/R.cs) to group attributes. In the `initialize` method below value of the `markup` parameter is the above string.

```
public class TextBox : DotLiquid.Tag
{
    //R.B and R.Q are dotliquid's utility method
    private static readonly Regex Syntax = R.B(R.Q(@"(?<validation>{0}+)(\s(?<label>{0}+))?(\s(?<name>{0}+))?(\s(?<onlyif>{0}+))?"), Liquid.QuotedFragment);

    private string[] _validations;
    private string[] _label;
    private string[] _name;
    private string[] _onlyif;

    public override void Initialize(string tagName, string markup, List<string> tokens)
    {
        var syntaxMatch = Syntax.Match(markup);
        if (syntaxMatch.Success)
        {
            _validations = syntaxMatch.Groups["validation"].Value.Split("=").TrimQuotes().ToArray();
            _label = syntaxMatch.Groups["label"].Value.Split("=").TrimQuotes().ToArray();
            _name = syntaxMatch.Groups["name"].Value.Split("=").TrimQuotes().ToArray();
            _onlyif = syntaxMatch.Groups["onlyif"].Value.Split("=").TrimQuotes().ToArray();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new SyntaxException("Invalid syntax");
        }

        base.Initialize(tagName, markup, tokens);
    }

    public override void Render(Context context, TextWriter result)
    {
        base.Render(context, result);
    }
}
```

The code is working with given string only, However there are issues:
1>If the attributes are in different order, then grouping get assigned wrong values.

2>`name` and `label` attributes are required but `validates` and `visibleif` attributes are not required. RegEx should validate this.

3>RegEx must fail if markup has any other extra attribute.

Can someone help with correct regular expression?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that if this would be what here we want to solve. However, it seems to me that we want to capture attribute values. If that would be the case, we might want to start with a simple expression, then modify and change if we like. For example, we can use:

```
(validates|label|name|visibleif)=("(.+?)")\s?
```

If we wish to fail other strings, that might be simple, however I'm not so sure about other possible and desired strings to make any suggestion.

[image]

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified or changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/v3fpif/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### Example Test

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"(validates|label|name|visibleif)=(""(.+?)"")\s?";
        string input = @"validates=""required positiveInteger"" label=""Enter the Total Value."" name=""totalvalue"" visibleif=""hasvalue:Yes""
validates=""required positiveInteger"" label=""Enter the Total Value."" name=""totalvalue"" visibleif=""hasvalue:Yes"" fail_attribute=""Undesired""";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Demo

```js
const regex = /(validates|label|name|visibleif)=("(.+?)")\s?/gm;
const str = `validates="required positiveInteger" label="Enter the Total Value." name="totalvalue" visibleif="hasvalue:Yes"
validates="required positiveInteger" label="Enter the Total Value." name="totalvalue" visibleif="hasvalue:Yes" fail_attribute="Undesired"`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/v3fpif/1/)

Comment: It worked if i loop as your code suggests. However if i group`Syntax.Match(markup)` then it does not return correct groups

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, for me it looks like you're trying to achieve too much with regex.

My assumption is that when you're splitting a string on `=`, then you get a key and a value. The key is the attribute name, so at this point you can validate whether `label` and `value` are provided, and there is nothing more than `label`, `value`, `validate` and `visibleif`.

This way the regex needs to be much simpler - you only need to split on whitespaces, so perhaps you don't even need regex at all?